# Saving XML file to isolated storage in WP8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, abbyy

I am working on an application for windows phone 8 that needs to scan several text fields from a picture and use the results. I am using ABBYY cloud OCR and I need the method processFields (link http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processFields/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=SMM), which its parameter is a path to a XML file with the coordinations of the fields. 
is anyone familiar with Isolated storage on windows phone 8 and can help me save a XML file to it (or write to it)?

Answer (score 0):

may this will help you .[Here is more abouthow to use isolated storage in wp8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/File_manipulation_with_IsolatedStorageFile_on_Windows_Phone)

```
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestFile.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, fileStorage));
Writer.WriteLine(xml_string);
Writer.Close();
```